# Shiny app does not work on Google Chrome/Chromium

Tags: r, shiny

I am working on an open data project that includes a dashboard: https://shiny.tradestatistics.io/dashboard/

I have used recent shiny-server, shinyjs and shinydashboard versions, and it works ok on Firefox and Edge, but on Chrome it fails and shows an "aw, snap" message.

The logs show no errors, warnings or strange signs. Any idea of what can be happening?

Here's my session info:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas/libblas.so.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenblasp-r0.2.20.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=C.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C           LC_TIME=C.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=C.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=C.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=C.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=C.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C             
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C           LC_TELEPHONE=C         LC_MEASUREMENT=C.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C   

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] d3po_0.1.1                magrittr_1.5              htmlwidgets_1.3           tradestatistics_0.2.1    
[5] tidyr_0.8.3               dplyr_0.8.3               shinydashboard_0.7.1.8000 shinyjs_1.0              
[9] shiny_1.3.2              

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.2         RColorBrewer_1.1-2 pillar_1.4.2       compiler_3.5.1     later_0.8.0        tokenizers_0.2.1  
 [7] tools_3.5.1        statquotes_0.2.2   digest_0.6.20      lattice_0.20-38    jsonlite_1.6       tibble_2.1.3      
[13] pkgconfig_2.0.2    rlang_0.4.0        Matrix_1.2-17      rstudioapi_0.10    crul_0.8.0         curl_4.0          
[19] yaml_2.2.0         janeaustenr_0.1.5  stringr_1.4.0      generics_0.0.2     wordcloud_2.6      grid_3.5.1        
[25] tidyselect_0.2.5   glue_1.3.1         httpcode_0.2.0     R6_2.4.0           purrr_0.3.2        SnowballC_0.6.0   
[31] promises_1.0.1     htmltools_0.3.6    assertthat_0.2.1   tidytext_0.2.1     mime_0.7           xtable_1.8-4      
[37] httpuv_1.5.1       stringi_1.4.3      crayon_1.3.4
```

Answer (score 1):

I can open this link (https://shiny.tradestatistics.io/dashboard/) correctly in Chrome at my end. No problems. Google has a page for "Aw,Snap!" error (https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95669?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en). You may want to check which one is applicable for you.All the best.